# StepDefinition does not work when there are more than one object in Json

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest-assured

Below is my Rest Method

```
public String OrdersSuspend(String ordersSuspendJson) {
    Response respOrder = ctx.post(ORDERSSUSPEND,ordersSuspendJson).then().
            statusCode(200).extract().response();
    return respOrder.getBody().asString();
}
```

Below is my Step Definition

```
  orderResponse.ifPresent(o -> {
            orderSuspendResponse = restCalls.OrdersSuspend("[" + o.toJson() + "]");
        });
  orderResponse.ifPresent(o -> {
            orderResponse = Optional.ofNullable(restCalls.restgetOrder(o.getId()));
        });
```

Above code works well when the request payload is

```
[
 {id: 16042, version: 1}
]

 0: {id: 16042, version: 1}
```

It does not work when there are more than 1 object

```
[
 {id: 16042, version: 3},
 {id: 16043, version: 0}
]

 0: {id: 16042, version: 3}
 1: {id: 16043, version: 0}
```

Comment: Are you using Rest Assured post() method to make a request?

Comment: Where is `orderResponse` defined? Is it a field? It seems strange to change the field value during the call to `ifPresent`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException

private Optional<Order> orderResponse = Optional.of(new Order());

Order class has all the get and set methods of the attributes for Orders Json

Comment: @bhusak yes I am using Rest Assured Post method

Comment: @bhusak :

toJson method which i am using 

                   public String toJson() {
                   return "{\"id\":"+id+",\"version\":"+version+"}";
                   }

Comment: @LavishKhetan Rest Assured post() method accepts _path_ value and optional _path params_. If you want to send JSON use body(String body) method from [rest assured doc](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#request-body)